# Magento 2 How to get First Item from getList()?

Tags: magento2

I want to get only the first item from the SearchCriteriaBuilder result is there any method that gives direct first item?
currently using getList()->getItems() then for loop forget single item....
so I just want to know is there any shortcut method which gives the first record.....

```
class Promo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
    protected $sales_rule;
    protected $search_builder;
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context,\Magento\SalesRule\Api\RuleRepositoryInterface $sales_rule,\Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $search_builder,array $data = array()){
        $this->sales_rule=$sales_rule;
        $this->search_builder=$search_builder;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getPromoDetail(){
        $sales_rule=array();
        $searchCriteria = $this->search_builder->addFilter('is_active',1,'eq')->addFilter('is_popup_rule',1,'eq')->create();
        $items = $this->sales_rule->getList($searchCriteria);
        foreach ($items->getItems() as $value) {
            $sales_rule[]=$value;
        }
        return $sales_rule[0]    ;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup]);
$searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
$searchCriteria->setPageSize(1)
               ->setCurrentPage(1);

$productList = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
$item = current($productList->getItems());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [reset](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.reset.php) function

```
$searchResults = $this->sales_rule->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
$firstItem = reset($searchResults);
```

Comment: Hmmm.. It's not said that the first element has index 0